# Textbook recommendation for multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

Can anyone recommend a textbook for double and triples integrals.
I'd like one that covers double integrals in polar coordinates and triples integrals with cylindrical and spherical coordinates. Ideally i'd like one with plenty of practice questions and solutions. Online material is fine as well.

Comment: It doesn't have many practice problems, but http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ is a good place to check out. It's free as well

Answer (score 1):

A great ressource is *MIT OpenCourseWare*. There are video lectures, lecture notes, even assignement, exams and the solutions for them.

- There is [MIT $18.02$, *Multivariable Calculus*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/) given by Prof. Denis Auroux. The textbook used for thi course is [*Multivariable Calculus. 6th ed.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130339679) by Edwards, Henry C., and David E. Penney.

> This course covers vector and multi-variable calculus. It is the second semester in the freshman calculus sequence. Topics include vectors and matrices, partial derivatives, double and triple integrals, and vector calculus in $2$ and $3$-space.
>
> *MIT OpenCourseWare* offers another version of $18.02$, from the Spring $2006$ term. Both versions cover the same material, although they are taught by different faculty and rely on different textbooks.

- If you prefer deeper Mathematics, you can also look at [MIT $18.022$, *Calculus of Several Sariables*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-022-calculus-of-several-variables-fall-2010/) a course given by Prof. James McKernan.

> This is a variation on $18.02$, *Multivariable Calculus*. It covers the
> same topics as in $18.02$, but with more focus on mathematical concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I used to learn it from Stewart Calculus.

You can also check out Multivariable Calculus (18.02) From MIT OCW

Comment: do you mean stewart calculus?

Comment: This book teaches by example, a method which while possibly useful for computational fluency, denies the reader many opportunities to get a good conceptual understanding.

Comment: @er44 thank you. Yes Stewart.